# Impact of Various "Feminizing" Hormones on Metabolism

Tags: side-effects, endocrinology, metabolism, appetite

I've read that progesterone is linked to changes in metabolism and appetite, and that those undergoing hormone therapy with progesterone often experience profound changes in hunger and meal habits.

I haven't managed to easily anything confirming/denying similar metabolic effects from estrogen or anti-androgens, but is this a plausible side-effect of "feminizing" hormones generally?

Answer (score 2):

There is peer-reviewed scientific research [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221781015_Sex_hormones_appetite_and_eating_behaviour_in_women) "Sex hormones, appetite and eating behaviour in women" by Angelica Lindén Hirschberg
from *Karolinska Institutet*, which states already in abstract

> Sex hormones play essential roles in the regulation of appetite, eating behaviour and energy metabolism and have been implicated in several major clinical disorders in women. Estrogen inhibits food intake, whereas progesterone and testosterone may stimulate appetite.

More detailed answer, including various small details are on pp.249-250 of article, part 2.4 *Sex hormones*. Rest of article covers woman's various stages of life and deviations from norm, so whole paper worth reading.

Quoting is limited to above due to apparent copyright limitations.